# Android: How to stream music using default player?

Tags: android, streaming

I want to stream mp3 song using default media player.

I used the MIME Type  "audio/*".

```
Intent musicIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
musicIntent.setType("audio/*");
startActivity(musicIntent);
```

so how to stream music via default music player?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply pass the url to Media Player like this,

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("your url here");
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "audio/*"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks it works but can i change the name of the song in th player because it the url i passed.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know whether you will be able to do it.

Comment: when i stream a song so its work but the name of the song in the media player bar is the url so i am looking to change the name of the song.

Comment: hi
dod u get any solution for this.
the url is displaying with the mediaplayer
and i dont want to show url..
plz help

Comment: Could you use Name:Value pairs and pass the Name of the Song to the player? that should display the name rather than the url