# How to stream music from url with Java - Android

Tags: java, android, ios, audio, stream

I'm totally new to Android Development and to Android devices in general, so I don't know how things are working here.

I want to make an app that will stream music from my url and still playing the song after I minimize the application.

I searched my question but a lot of answers were for mp3 songs or other types, but my url is from a live radio so it isn't one song only.

One of the answers that I found and were good for my problem was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907068/android-how-to-stream-music-using-default-player) and uses this code:

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("your url here");
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "audio/*"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

This prompt me to choose a music player.

Is there any way to just press my "play" button and hear the music?

In my iOS app I use this code and I can start and stop the streaming music whenever I want without an external player:

```
func prepareToPlay() {
        
        let url = URL(string: "myUrl")
        
        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
        
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
          
        player?.play()
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

After suggested in comments and answer I tried to play it with `MPlayer`, I made a function and I called it when I tapped my button like this:

```
public void playM() {
    String url = "http://android.programmerguru.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hosannatelugu.mp3";

    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    mPlayer.start();
}
```

But I get an error (the fourth message) and I saw in the logs this:

> Unable to create media player
>
> prepareAsync called in state 1, mPlayer(0x0)
>
> start called in state 1, mPlayer(0x0)
>
> error (-38, 0)

Comment: What [network protocol](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#network) is your server using?

Comment: @CommonsWare It uses http

Comment: AFAIK, that wasn't specific enough -- see the docs that I linked to. You're welcome to hand the URL over to `MediaPlayer` and see if it works.

Comment: @CommonsWare check my edit if you want.

Comment: "Unable to create media player" => seems you did not add permissions in the manifest "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intent is using only for sending some data between activities/services and system. It won't play the music. It don't do anything except saying to some activity what to do. You need the mechanism which will play your multimedia stream. You should use [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class for playing multimedia inside your application.

Here's some tutorial, how to play music from stream: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-mediaplayer-example-play-from-internet/

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, if you want check my edit

Comment: Did you see in the end of page adding permission code?

Comment: as I was checking if all were working well I noticed that the first time I play the play button the music starts for 8 sec and then stops for about 10 sec after that (without pressing any button or minimize the app) the music plays without stopping..

Answer (score 3):

Intent with ACTION flag is intended to open another app in most cases. Since you don't need it. You want your own custom player. So Android has a Media Player class for such scenarios.

Create instance of it and pass your stream-URL. Now, set the data-source and call prepare() after that in `onBtnClickListener()` start the music by calling `mp.start()`

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

P.S: Catch all the exceptions and make sure the PERMISSIONS in manifest file